# PHP Facebook Application jSON issue

Tags: php, json, facebook

I am developing a Facebook Application in which I need to view the user_work_history data of a profile. Im doing this in PHP, and Facebook's Documentation is very cryptic and terrible.

In the documentation (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), it says "An array of JSON objects containing employer, location, position, start_date and end_date fields". I assumed I would access this by doing something along the lines of `<?php echo $me[work]; ?>` however that only returns "array" in the output.

I've tried various things such as `<?php echo $me[work][employer]; ?>` which didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated and recognized!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing a `var_dump($me['work'])` or whatever to get a clearer look into what's inside that variable.

Additionally, you can get your access token by calling `$fb_object->getAccessToken();` and use that in this URL: `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<whatever>`. Navigating to that in your browser will show you what data is coming back so you can get a better idea of the formatting.

- [`var_dump` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: Thank you Jimmy! That seems to have worked, I'll just need to figure out how to parse the data to get a specific string and I'll be set! I'll "accept" this answer as soon as Stackoverflow will let me :)